# C# read data from excel file results in ###

Tags: c#, .net, excel, range, worksheet

i read data from an excel file with this code

```
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range;

        int rCnt = 0;
        int cCnt = 0;
        string[,] data;

        xlWorkSheet = (Worksheet)wb.Worksheets.get_Item(sheetId);

        range = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange;

        data = new string[range.Rows.Count, range.Columns.Count];

        for (rCnt = 1; rCnt <= range.Rows.Count; rCnt++)
        {
            for (cCnt = 1; cCnt <= range.Columns.Count; cCnt++)
            {          
                data[rCnt - 1, cCnt - 1] = (string)
                (range.Cells[rCnt, cCnt] as Range).Text;
            }
        }
```

Now i am running sometimes into cells where the value in excel is displayed as ### because the column space is not big enough to display the number. In excel of course i can see the right value in the line on the top when i click on the cell but in my program i am getting the ### as value instead of the right number.

Any advice here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using [`Range.Value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.value%28v=office.11%29.aspx) property instead of `Text`.

So instead of

```
(range.Cells[rCnt, cCnt] as Range).Text;
```

you would write

```
(range.Cells[rCnt, cCnt] as Range).Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

I have seen numerous examples where the Range is read using the property Value OR Value2.
Could you try this?

```
data[rCnt - 1, cCnt - 1] = (string)(range.Cells[rCnt, cCnt] as Range).Value.ToString();
```

The Value2 property is similar to Value but don't translate well the Date columns, so it's better to use the Value if you have date columns in your Excel File. [See here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/182812) for an article on differences between Value and Value2

Answer (score 0):

use (string) (range.Cells[rCnt, cCnt] as Range).Value as Value will return the actual value of a cell. Text will return what you actually see on the spreadsheet